# "this.grades.push is not a function" When trying to add a Grade to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

Hi I'm creating a webapp where I can list my grades and take the average of it but I can't add any Grades to my Array with a Button. When I click on the Add Button I get the error message:

```
TypeError: this.grades.push is not a function

at VueComponent.addGrade (Calculator.vue?1876:54)

at click (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-
```

I am also trying to save the grades in a Local Storage. What am I doing wrong?

I am doing everthing with Vue.js and js.
Here the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Grade-Calculator</h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(g,idx) in grades" :key="idx">
          {{idx+1}}. Grade : {{g}}
          <button v-on:click="delGrade()">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <label>New Grade:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="newGrade" />
        <button v-on:click="addGrade()">Add</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <p>Average: {{ calcAvg() | round}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<!-- The Script-->
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    grades: [],
    newGrade: 0,
    avg: 0,
    formattedNumber: ""
  }),
  name: "Home",
  props: {},

  methods: {
    calcAvg: function() {
      let sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.grades.length; i++) {
        let num = parseInt(this.grades[i]);
        sum = sum + num;
      }
      console.log(sum);
      console.log(this.grades.length);
      return sum / this.grades.length;
    },
    addGrade: function() {
      if (this.grades == null) {
        this.grades = [];
      }
      this.grades.push(this.newGrade);
      this.newGrade = 0;
      localStorage.setItem("grades", this.grades);
    },
    delGrade: function() {
      var idx = this.grades.indexOf(this.grades);
      this.grades.splice(idx);
      localStorage.removeItem("grades");
      localStorage.setItem("grades", this.grades);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.grades = localStorage.getItem("grades");
  },
  filters: {
    round: function(value) {
      value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
      //this.formattedNumber = this.avg.toFixed(2);
      return value;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web storage stores **strings**, so the problem is in `mounted`:

```
this.grades = localStorage.getItem("grades");
```

Now, `this.grades` is a string, which doesn't have a `push` method.

Store your array as JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem("grades", JSON.stringify(this.grades));
```

and parse it on retrieval:

```
this.grades = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("grades")) || [];
```

The `|| []` part gives you a blank array if the item isn't in storage (`getItem` returns `null`, which will get converted to `"null"` and then parsed by `JSON.parse` back to `null`, which is falsy).

Comment: The addGrades works now thanks. But it doesn't save the grades in the Local Storage. When I reload the page the Local Storage gets deleted. Anything on that?

Comment: @JEA - I've you've modified your code to save the grades as shown in the answer, it should work.

Comment: It saves it in the Local Storage but when I reload the Website the Local Storage gets cleared.

Comment: @JEA - `localStorage` is not cleared when you load a page, so something in your code must be clearing it. You'll need to find whatever that is. Assuming the code in `mounted` has been updated to `this.grades = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("grades")) || [];` and that code is run when your component is mounted (I don't do Vue.js), nothing in the code in the question is clearing it.

Comment: Thanks found the problem.